# Rendering an Output Panel when a Google Recaptcha returns false

Tags: rerender

I want to rerender the output panel with id,Captchapanel.It is working fine when the recaptcha returns true.But it is not rendering the outputpanel when recaptcha return false.Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

.star
       {
          color: red;
        }
        .error 
       {
            text-shadow: .5px .5px red;
       }
    
    
     
    
     
          $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.validateForm').validate();

```
    $('.txtNameClass').rules("add",{
                  required: true
    });
      $('.txtEmailClass').rules("add",{
               required: true,
                  email: true
     });

    $('.btnRecaptchaClass').click(function()
          {

     callVerifyApexMethod();


                return false;
    });
  jQuery.validator.messages.required = "Please enter a valid value!";
  jQuery.validator.messages.email = "Your email contains invalid characters!";


  });
```

Create Work With HEB
         
             
            *Work With Me Name*
                 
                     
                 
            
            
            Email

```
                       <apex:outputPanel  rendered="{!NOT(verified)}"  >

                           <script  src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k={!publicKey}"/>



                                </apex:outputPanel>  
              <apex:actionFunction name="callVerifyApexMethod" action="{!verify}" reRender="captchaPanel" />  
                <apex:commandButton onclick="validate()"  styleClass="btnRecaptchaClass slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-top--medium" value="Check If I'm Human"  rendered="{!NOT(verified)}" />

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!verified}">
                    <p class="slds-theme_success" >reCAPTCHA verification suggests that youre not a bot.</p>
                </apex:outputPanel>  

                     </apex:outputPanel>
                 </apex:actionRegion>


                </div>
           <div class="slds-modal__footer">
           <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-top--medium" value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
             <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-top--medium" value="Close" onclick="return false;"  />
            </div>
```